# In Sleight, how did Bo change the card in the young woman's hand?

Tags: realism, sleight

*Sleight* (2017) included a lot of magic tricks. Some of the tricks involving magnetism had a "scientific" (but impossible/ridiculous) explanation.

The movie also included card tricks.  In one of Bo's card tricks on the street, a young woman is holding a card (8 of clubs) so it faces Bo. He asks her to imagine any other card, and when she looks again at the card she is holding, it has magically changed into the card she imagined (3 of diamonds). Was that trick ever explained in the movie (like with the magnetism tricks, and most of the tricks *Now You See Me*)? Or is the audience just supposed to suspend disbelief?

[image]